# Selenium csv export button to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I am using selenium to click on a button that allows to export data as csv. However I would like to know if instead of downloading the file it would be possible to put the data in a DataFrame or in a variable ?

That's the command I use to download the file:

`driver.execute_script("window.open('" + export_url + "');")`

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use directly [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function to download file and transform into Dataframe.

The parameter `filepath_or_buffer` allows external URLs. See a example below:

```
import pandas as pandas

export_url = 'http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv'
df = pandas.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=export_url, sep=',', lineterminator='\r')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
                              street             city  ...   latitude   longitude
0                       3526 HIGH ST       SACRAMENTO  ...  38.631913 -121.434879
1                        51 OMAHA CT       SACRAMENTO  ...  38.478902 -121.431028
2                     2796 BRANCH ST       SACRAMENTO  ...  38.618305 -121.443839
3                   2805 JANETTE WAY       SACRAMENTO  ...  38.616835 -121.439146
4                    6001 MCMAHON DR       SACRAMENTO  ...  38.519470 -121.435768
5                 5828 PEPPERMILL CT       SACRAMENTO  ...  38.662595 -121.327813
```

Comment: Hey @Kafels thank you for your answer. I know `pandas.read_csv` however it is not working in this case. I need to be logged in to download the file and that's why I use selenium. Your solution only returns me JavaScript of the page in a DataFrame

Comment: Can you share the URL and more steps of your code to export csv? Because I think the unique way to export csv with selenium and import as Dataframe it's downloading to local file then import it passing absolute path

Comment: That's what I ended up doing because I didn't find a manner to download the file directly to memory. But thanks for your help